# Having trouble getting the last id in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the last id added to the database using `mysql_insert_id` but it doesn't work. The error I get is:

> mysql_insert_id() [function.mysql-insert-id]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in /proj/co639/assessment2/nicp3/public_html/book_create.php on line 46
>
> Warning: mysql_insert_id() [function.mysql-insert-id]: A link to the server could not be established in /proj/co639/assessment2/nicp3/public_html/book_create.php on line 46

I've done my connection like this:

```
$handle = new PDO( 'mysql:host=;dbname=', '', '');
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: You are mixing PDO and the old ext/mysql functions; they are not compatible. For your established PDO connection, you need to use http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: it gives me this error now

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in /proj/co639/assessment2/nicp3/public_html/bool.php on line 41

Fatal error: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on a non-object in /proj/co639/assessment2/nicp3/public_html/bool.php on line 41

Comment: Your connection is called `$handle`, not `$dbh`.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually looking for this:

```
$handle->beginTransaction();
// here you execute your query
$handle->commit();
$id = $handle->lasInsertId();
```

Your code won't work because you mix two different classes.

More information can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: ive got it to now but it just returns 0 when i echo it out instead of the id on the database

Comment: You need to insert something in database (using php not manually) then it will give you the last id.

Comment: $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO books (tie,aus,des,pr,im,co)  VALUES(:tie,:aus,:des,:pr,:im,:co)";
  $query = $handle->prepare($sql_2); 
   
 $params = array(':title'=> $title,':authors'=> $authors,':description'=> $description,':price'=> $price,':image'=> $image,':content'=> $content);
 $query -> execute($params); 
$ids = $handle->lastInsertId();
 echo $ids;